# Delete all the entries in 15 second intervals if the number of entries are less than a certain number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this
[image]

I am trying to resample the data on 15 second itnerval with mean of the data.
If the number of entries in the resample is less than 100, i just want to delete all entries corresponding to that 15 S seconds interval and have all the entries not just resampled dataframe.

```
ff = df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp').count()['Timestamp']
```

output

```
Timestamp
2016-04-18 09:31:30      2
2016-04-18 09:31:45    275
2016-04-18 09:32:00    258
2016-04-18 09:32:15    255
2016-04-18 09:32:30    263
2016-04-18 09:32:45    246
```

all the timestamps in the 15 second intervals with value less than 100 should be deleted.
How do i do that?

Comment: Let me ask "why?" first. Having a second, independent, process that scrubs your database every few minutes instead of every 15 seconds makes a lot more sense than trying to make a single script pull both "data analysis" duty _and_ database maintenance duty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) with filtering only rows of original DataFrame with [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.count.html) higher as `100`, also convert boolena mask to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for avoid `UserWarning`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': ['2016-04-18 09:31:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:31:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:31:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:41:31',
          '2016-04-18 09:41:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:51:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:51:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:31:30',
          '2016-04-18 09:31:30'],
    'B': list(range(9))
})
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
print (df)
             Timestamp  B
0  2016-04-18 09:31:30  0
1  2016-04-18 09:31:30  1
2  2016-04-18 09:31:30  2
3  2016-04-18 09:41:31  3
4  2016-04-18 09:41:30  4
5  2016-04-18 09:51:30  5
6  2016-04-18 09:51:30  6
7  2016-04-18 09:31:30  7
8  2016-04-18 09:31:30  8
```

---

```
#in real data N = 100
N = 2
ff = df[df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp')['Timestamp'].transform('count').values > N]
print (ff)
            Timestamp  B
0 2016-04-18 09:31:30  0
1 2016-04-18 09:31:30  1
2 2016-04-18 09:31:30  2
3 2016-04-18 09:41:31  3
4 2016-04-18 09:41:30  4
```

Comment: # integer comparisons        
  
if is_datetimelike_v_numeric(x, y):

 raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
i got this error

Comment: One idea, how working `ff = df[df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp')['Timestamp'].transform('count').values > 100]` ?

Comment: ff = df[df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp').transform('count').values > 100]
This worked you can edit the answer i will accept it.Thankyou

Comment: @subhashnerella - Code is different, you forget for `['Timestamp']`

Comment: ff = df[df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp').transform('count').values > 2] This is working but this ff = df[df.resample('15S', on='Timestamp')['Timestamp'].transform('count').values > 2] is not working. My pandas version is 0.22.0. Is the difference in behaviour is due to the version?

Comment: @subhashnerella - yes, you are right. My code was tested in `pandas 0.23.4`